# How do cellphones calculate heart rate?

Tags: cardiology, blood-pressure

How do cellphones calculate heart rate ? I understand that the cameras there try to count undulation in blood flow, but is the method of calculation same as that of professional SpO2 monitors ?

Comment: I'm not sure this question is on topic here - it's about technology and apps. But assuming you mean how do apps like [this one](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/instant-heart-rate-heart-rate/id409625068?mt=8) calculate HR. I believe it measures fluctuations in the colour of the skin (it will change as the quantity of blood varies in the capillaries with pulsing action) and it is simply a case of X beats in 10 seconds = 6*X bpm. [SpO2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_saturation_in_medicine#Measurement) is a measure of oxygen saturation, not heart rate.

Comment: @GriffinEvo Thus us exactly how it is done. The "redness" of the skin changes with the heart rate and this is measured. See this [reference](http://www.fruct.org/publications/abstract12/files/Lau.pdf). I would suggest you make it a real answer.

Comment: @GriffinEvo I was not sure where the question belonged, this looked the most relevant forum.

Comment: I asked a [related question](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/19940/can-the-xbox-kinect-sensor-accurately-assess-your-heart-rate-across-the-room) on Skeptics recently and was pointed to [this work](http://people.csail.mit.edu/mrub/vidmag/) - it appears to be detecting changes in skin colour related to heart rate.

Comment: Wouldn't this work out only for people with a very fair complexion ??

Comment: @WYSIWYG: if you look at ~1:40 of the the Siggraph 2012 video you will see that the algorithm works for dark skin tones too.

Comment: @GriffinEvo I agree with Chris, try to make this into an answer. You can also incorporate information given by others.